# Change the buttonText of add-in button through Exec function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exec, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I saw several times in the MSDN this sentence:
"Add-ins can later change the ButtonText name by responding to the QueryStatus method".
But never saw how to do it. someone can help me?

I want to change the add-in button text (the text that appears on the button) when user hits the add-in button. For example: I have an add-in that its text is `LogOn`. I want to change this text to `LogOut` when the user presses it.

Thanks!